# how to disable the flash button using javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application i'm using swf upload library to upload the images.
Now i need to disable that flash button.any suggestions would be appreciative.

thanks mani

Comment: are u in any case using yui swf uploader?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `<object id="flash_upload_but">....</object>` is the HTML Code for your flash button.

You need to create an image with the same looking like the flash button, then append the image right after the flash-button with css "`display:none`". Once you want to disable the flash-button, just hide it & show the substitute image.

```
<object id="flash_upload_but">....</object>
<img id="fake_flash_but" src="fake_flash_but.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<script>
   function disable_uploadbut(){
      $('#fake_flash_but').show()
      $('#flash_upload_but').hide()
   }

   //in case in want to re-enable it
   function enable_uploadbut(){
      $('#fake_flash_but').hide()
      $('#flash_upload_but').show()
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [setButtonDisabled](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#setButtonDisabled) method.